# Get all k-item subsets of a list L without recursion?

Tags: python, generics, computer-science

```
permutation(['Alice','Charles','Bob'],2)
Output:- [['Alice', 'Charles'], ['Alice', 'Bob'], ['Charles', 'Alice'], ['Charles', 'Bob'], ['Bob', 'Alice'], ['Bob', 'Charles']]
```

I want implementation of sublist without recursion.
I can't use any additional library/imports.
Any leads or hints to solve this ?

Comment: Is this a homework?

Comment: I have implemented a SAT solver.I want to convert a optimisation problem into a CNF form.I need a k subset for maintaining a constraint.I have implemented a recursive version but it shows memory error

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) of `permutations` of `itertools` module?

*Roughly equivalent to:*

```
def permutations(iterable, r=None):
    # permutations('ABCD', 2) --> AB AC AD BA BC BD CA CB CD DA DB DC
    # permutations(range(3)) --> 012 021 102 120 201 210
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    r = n if r is None else r
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = list(range(n))
    cycles = list(range(n, n-r, -1))
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices[:r])
    while n:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            cycles[i] -= 1
            if cycles[i] == 0:
                indices[i:] = indices[i+1:] + indices[i:i+1]
                cycles[i] = n - i
            else:
                j = cycles[i]
                indices[i], indices[-j] = indices[-j], indices[i]
                yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices[:r])
                break
        else:
            return
```

So, without recursion, without import, etc:

```
>>> permutations(['Alice','Charles','Bob'],2)
[('Alice', 'Charles'),
 ('Alice', 'Bob'),
 ('Charles', 'Alice'),
 ('Charles', 'Bob'),
 ('Bob', 'Alice'),
 ('Bob', 'Charles')]
```

Comment: Using this method gives memory error.What could be the reason ?

Comment: With your sample???

Comment: I have implemented a SAT solver.I want to convert a optimisation problem into a CNF form.I need a k subset for maintaining a constraint.I have implemented a recursive version but it shows memory error.

Comment: It's a quiz scheduling problem,so one constraint is to have at most one student in each room.So I have converted this into "For all possible pair of rooms, a student should be in either of the room or absent".

Comment: How long is your input and how big your k? Could the memory error occur somewhere else in your code?